# How to change hive table owner

Tags: hive

I have a hive table 'sample' created with owner as 'X'

```
hive> show table extended like sample;
```

--shows owner as 'X'

Is there a way I can change the owner to some other 'Y', without recreating the table (don't want to lose the data)

A known option is to update the owner directly in the postgres hive metastore table.

```
hive=# update "TBLS" set "OWNER" = 'Y' where "OWNER" = 'X' and "TBL_NAME" = 'sample';
```

Is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no other way to do it besides direct change in metastore DB. I needed to do this couple of times - there were no any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue and can share my resolution notes, to add color to what a "Direct Change in The Metastore DB" for me.  In our configuration, we're using Presto that connects to Hive.  Tables will be created in hive with whatever user that Presto connects as (with the `--user` flag on the Presto CLI).

We were getting an error message such as:

```
Access Denied: Cannot drop table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME: Owner of the table is 
different from session user
```

I can see the users of the table by executing the following query on the Hive Metastore:

```
select t.OWNER, p.PRINCIPAL_NAME, count(1) 
from TBLS t 
    join TBL_PRIVS p on p.TBL_ID=t.TBL_ID 
group by t.OWNER, p.PRINCIPAL_NAME;
```

And then, I can update the tables as needed by executing:

```
update TBLS set OWNER='NEW_OWNER' where OWNER='OLD_OWNER';
update TBL_PRIVS set PRINCIPAL_NAME='NEW_OWNER' where PRINCIPAL_NAME='OLD_OWNER';
```

**NOTE:** You should run this in a transaction and make sure your Metastore is backed up first.